# Android using back button

Tags: android

i wanna use the back button on the mobile itself to make a dialog box appear to ask me whether am sure i wanna exit or not?

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setTitle("Confirm");
    dialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
    return;
 }



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Text);
    TextWatcher watch=new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            onBackPressed();
        }
    };
    text.addTextChangedListener(watch);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As i considered your `onBackPressed()` is the override method to handle android back key.

Just add `dialog.create().show()` to your `onBackPressed();`.

It will display **AlertDialog**..

Also removed `onBackPressed();` from `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` else it will calling every time when user try to enter some character in `EditText`..

**Update:**

one more thing your `onBackPressed()` should be like,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
 super.onBackPressed();

 AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TestActivity.this);
 dialog.setTitle("Confirm");
 dialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
 dialog.create().show();
}
```

Change if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for back button event

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
     onBackPressed();
     return true;
   }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

this is alert dialog

```
private void onBackPressed() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Do you really want to exit?");
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    ThisActivity.this.finish();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });             
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); 
            alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) 
    {
        showDialogForCloseApplication();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private void showDialogForCloseApplication()
    {
        try
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.name));
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
               {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                   {
                       finish();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
               {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                   {
                        dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Way :**try as by @Override `onKeyDown` method in your Current Activity:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        showAlert("", "Do you really want to exit?");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private void showAlert(final String title, final String msg) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialouge = new AlertDialog.Builder(CategoriesList.this);
    dialouge.setMessage(msg);
    dialouge.setPositiveButton(" Yes ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick( DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            CurrentActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
    dialouge.setNegativeButton(" No ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        }
    });
    dialouge.show();
}
```

**Second Way:** by @Override  `onBackPresed()`

```
public void onBackPresed(){

   Log.d(TAG,"inside onBackPressed()");
       showAlert("", "Do you really want to exit?");
}
```